# JavaScript: play a sound on window.location changing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that takes the user to a **different HTML doc**, and I want it to **make a noise** when they click it.

At this moment, i **set a long enough delay** for the sound to go off. However, this causes my **site to lag** (and it already loads pages pretty slowly).

Any thoughts?

```
// code for playing button then going to the next page
function buttonClick() {
  document.getElementById("buttonSound").play();
  window.setTimeout(levelSelect, 300);
}
```

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: @poolfork based on my understanding, you can redirect right away without waiting to a different html page, "X" for example, with specific query string, in that page called "X" do a simple check in load whether you have this query string passed in the url, then play your audio/noise

Comment: The only way I can think of to play a sound through completion while simultaneously loading another page would be with an `iframe` (apart from converting the site into a single-page app). The `iframe` option would only work if the button is part of a static UI that stays the same between pages, if that makes sense (in other words, the button can be outside of the frame that's changing). Without seeing an example of how the project is laid out though, it's hard to give anything concrete.

Comment: @msoliman looking over the example code, it appears as though the desired result is to play the sound instantly on click and simultaneously load another page while the sound is playing, hence the 300ms delay before the redirect, but they don't want to have that 300ms delay because it adds to response time.

Comment: @ChrisClower thanks for your clarification though It seems from the comment in the code snippet he provided that he needs to play sound and then redirect to a another page `// code for playing button then going to the next page`

Comment: You can trigger location.href, when sound end playing.

Comment: @ChrisClower I've only ever worked on MVC projects, I didnt even consider making the app single-view. We are building a simple trivia app and are close to done, do you think there is merit to a single-view app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, please leave a comment or edit your question if I miss understood:

- If you want to play the audio after redirect:

You can redirect right away without waiting to a different html page, "X" for example, with specific query string, in that page called "X" do a simple check in load whether you have this query string passed in the url, then play your audio/noise

- If you want to play the audio before redirect/load iframe:
  Use `onended` event for `audio` and redirect or load your html when it gets fired:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

x.onended  = function(){
  //can do AJAX too in case you want to load partial html content
  window.location.href = "https://astimix.com";
}

function playAudio() { 
x.play();

}

function pauseAudio() { 
    x.pause(); 
}
```

```html
   

<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
```

Comment: Do you ever use pauseAudio()?